# SVG animation reduces width of separate vector in file

Tags: javascript, svg

I've been messing around with SVG path animations. My SVG has 2 layers in it; a grey egg and an orange egg. The orange egg animates over the top of the grey egg, this part works fine. However, both paths technically have the same width, but when I animate the orange egg, the grey egg's path looks like it's reduced by 50%.

Below is an image and the code.

```js
var path = document.querySelector('#egg-orange path');
var length = path.getTotalLength();
var percent = length/100;
var desiredPercent = 50;
var currentPercent = percent * (100 - desiredPercent); // 50%
// Clear any previous transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
  'none';
// Set up the starting positions
path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
// Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
// picks up the starting position before animating
path.getBoundingClientRect();
// Define our transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
  'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
// Go!
path.style.strokeDashoffset = currentPercent;
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 104.7 144.3" enable-background="new 0 0 104.7 144.3" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="egg-grey">
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#414042" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M99.3,92.2c0,25.7-20.8,46.5-46.5,46.5
  S6.3,117.8,6.3,92.2S27.2,5.7,52.8,5.7S99.3,66.5,99.3,92.2z"/>
</g>
<g id="egg-orange">
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F15A29" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M99.3,92.2c0,25.7-20.8,46.5-46.5,46.5
  S6.3,117.8,6.3,92.2S27.2,5.7,52.8,5.7S99.3,66.5,99.3,92.2z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue was because of the white fill on the orange egg. All i needed to do was add `fill-opacity="0"` and hey presto, all sorted!

```
<g id="egg-orange">
    <path fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#F15A29" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M99.3,92.2c0,25.7-20.8,46.5-46.5,46.5
        S6.3,117.8,6.3,92.2S27.2,5.7,52.8,5.7S99.3,66.5,99.3,92.2z"/>
</g>
```

**EDIT:**
As Paul mentioned below, you can just set fill to none and not need to touch opacity.

```
<g id="egg-orange">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#F15A29" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M99.3,92.2c0,25.7-20.8,46.5-46.5,46.5
        S6.3,117.8,6.3,92.2S27.2,5.7,52.8,5.7S99.3,66.5,99.3,92.2z"/>
</g>
```

Comment: `fill="none"` would have done it.  No need for you to change the opacity.

Comment: Thank you @PaulLeBeau i don't know why i didn't think of that haha